# How to show comma separated values of button on clicking it multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to output value of a button in a div when the button is clicked. On clicking it one time the value is outputted properly but what I am trying to do is output the value as many times the button is clicked in comma separated format.
For example -

```
<button class="click" value="car">Button</button>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

If I click this button 3 times then the output should be like car,car,car.
I am trying to do it this way but it's not working.

```
<script>
$(".click").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("selected");
var data=$(".click").map(function () {  
return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
$(".demo").text(data);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.isEmpty = function() {
       return !$.trim(this.html()).length;
    };
}(jQuery));

$(".click").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  const limit = 3, sep = ',', $demos = $(".demo");
  if($demos.html().split(sep).length < limit){
    $demos.append(($demos.isEmpty() ? '' : sep) + $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click" value="car">Button</button>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: It worked. And what If I want to stop outputting the values after 3 clicks? Is it possible?

Comment: I adjusted my code, it should be what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can append `,car` to the `textContent` every time the user clicks the button. You'll also need to store whether this was the first click in a boolean, and if it is, trim off the first character.

```js
var isFirst = true;
$(".click").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $('.demo').text(($('.demo').text() + ',car').substring(isFirst ? 1 : 0))
  isFirst = false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click" value="car">Button</button>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need comma separated value each time then try this

```
        var result = '';
        $(".click").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var data = $(".click").map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();       

            if ($(".demo").text() == "") {
                result = data;
            } else {
                result = result + ',' + data;
            }
            $(".demo").text(result);
        });
```